# Running a project in VSCode with Maven, which does run in Intellij, giving deploy error

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I have a Java project that is designed to be built with Maven.  I have instructions to use the Intellij IDE, and I know that when a friend uses the same project and follows those instructions, it will build and run successfully.

I could just install Intellij, but my main code editor is VSCode.  So I was hoping that I hoping I could stick with VSCode and run it with this.

I'm working on Windows 10.  I've used the Java code pack to install Java version 17, and I've installed Maven.  When I open the project it looks like this:

[image]

In Intellij I'm supposed to be able to right-click the `Game.java` file and choose to run the main method.  However, I don't seem to be able to do that here.  When I right-click the project in the Maven drop-down, it gives an option to deploy.  But when I click that I get the following error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project hw09: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]
```

I assume this is because the POM file was not set up for a command to deploy, but rather something like a "run" command.  But that isn't an option that Maven seems to give me.

I've also tried running the `Game.java` file by right-clicking and clicking `Run`, but it gives this error:

```
[Running] cd "c:\Users\blank\Desktop\hw09_local\hw09_local_temp\src\main\java\org\cis1200\" && javac Game.java && java Game
Game.java:13: error: package org.cis1200.mushroom does not exist
        Runnable game = new org.cis1200.mushroom.RunMushroomOfDoom();
                                                ^
1 error
```

I assume it's giving this error because whatever it's using to try to run the program isn't aware of the surrounding file context.  I assume that's what Maven is supposed to do for me.

So is there a way to run this project in VSCode?  Or was it simply designed to specifically be run in IntelliJ, and I have to use that?

Comment: You may want to get more experiences with java and maven projects first, before wanting to personalize your setup away from something that works.

Comment: Looks like you are using `Code Runner` to run your project, which is not recommended way to do it. (Code Runner cannot understand your project structure). Instead, you can open `Game.java`, above your main method, you should see shortcut buttons `Run | Debug`.

Comment: @ShengChen Ah, that seems to work better.  It turns out when I run it, one part of the program attempts to access a file stored in the project, and causes an error.  I'm guessing this is perhaps some sort of permission issue.  In any case, running it in VSCode seems like a bit of a challenge, so I decided to just install IntelliJ and not keep struggling with this.  Thanks for the help though!